# The Five Main Ones

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Here is a classic **A is to B** as **C is to D** puzzle. Try see if you can figure out the answer.

---

$F:BRW::I:GRW::P:GR::R:BRY::?:?$

---

**Note:** Some minor simplification was needed on some of them. But that shouldn't cause any problems solving the puzzle. Once you see the pattern, you'll realize what the simplification was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> S : RY

Reasoning:

> The left side of an analogy is the first letter of a country which defines a Romance language: France, Italy, Portugal, Romania. The right side of the analogy is the first letters of the colors on its national flag, sorted in alphabetical order.

> France: Blue, Red, White
>  Italy: Green, Red, White
>  Portugal: Green, Red
>  Romania: Blue, Red, Yellow
>
>  The missing member is Spain, with a red and yellow flag, hence S : RY.
>
>  As an additional check, notice that in the presented analogies the countries are also in alphabetical order.

Comment: This is ofc correct, well done!